# Changes made in ionic components does not reflect on browser

Tags: ionic3, components

When I create new component say e.g login component and  write some code in it, then it doesn't quickly respond on browser. I think this is major issue which not yet resolved.Any one has solution on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created any component using **ionic generate page** or **ionic generate page**, you need to start/run the Ionic application again. You need to stop and start **ionic serve** to reflect changes. 

Those commands add a module to your project and those will be reflected only after again you start building an application.

Comment: Yes you are right but for every component we should stop /start, which is not permanent solution for this...it should get reflted once we save or commit changes in edior like how we do with angular application.

Comment: Yes. I agreed on this point. But the issue is open on GitHub as well and also on Ionic Forum. Check https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1132 and https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-serve-with-livereloading-doesnt-work-anymore/98593. So only this hack works now.

Comment: Yes I know so only I raised this issue here so maybe I get solution from someone like you....